# Facebook app profile tab does not display content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I am trying to add a profile tab to my Facebook app. In the Facebook Edit App page, I have set the tab url to http://apps.facebook.com/my-suggestions-tu/pages/test. I only needed to enter "pages/test" in the text field; "http://apps.facebook.com/my-suggestions-tu/" was already supplied by Facebook.

I can view http://apps.facebook.com/my-suggestions-tu/pages/test just fine. I have also been able to add the application tab to my test Facebook page. However, the application tab does not display anything.

My app is running on Rails 2.2, using the Facebooker plugin.

Thanks,
George

Comment: Let me know if my answer did not solve your problem. If you can provide more details such as what is printed in your server log I may be able to offer other suggestions.

Comment: Thanks. The filters were something I completely did not consider. Anyway, I have a related question here, perhaps you might want to take a look :) 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/700621/how-can-i-add-facebook-pages-as-users-to-a-facebook-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the `:ensure_application_is_installed_by_facebook_user` and/or `:ensure_authenticated_to_facebook` before_filters are not executed.

One way to do this would be to create a separate controller to handle the profile tab.

For example:

```
class TabsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :ensure_application_is_installed_by_facebook_user
  def index
   render :text => "tab content"
  end
end
```

(tab url would be just 'tab')

Keep in mind that the `fb_sig_user` facebook parameter is not available on the tab, so if you have an filters that rely on it they will not work.

Comment: You might be right. I looked at the script server log and I see it's encountering the following error: Filter chain halted as [:facebook_login_required] rendered_or_redirected.

Comment: Yeah, you're using the facebook_authentication plugin. You'll need to skip facebook_login_required method on the tab.

Comment: Hello Gdeglin, I got the same problem with gsmendoza, and finally make it through too, but my question is how to extract application tab owner facebook id ?

Comment: ahhhh, finally, it seem in parameters there are fb_sig_profile_user, and with that I can withdraw owner of the tab id....